# Add grand average as both line and circle + add the entry in the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean

I would like to add to plot 1) the grand average over subjects and repetitions for each condition; and 2) add this item on the legend.

Using this code (**EDIT**: I made a similar df to play with my question):

```
Npoint = 12; Ncond = 7; Nrep = 3; Nsubj = 2;

data_a <- c(sample(c(-2,22), Nrep*Npoint, replace = TRUE), sample(c(38,60), Nrep*Npoint, replace = TRUE), 
        sample(c(46,62), Nrep*Npoint, replace = TRUE), sample(c(26,44), Nrep*Npoint, replace = TRUE),
        sample(c(42,58), Nrep*Npoint, replace = TRUE), sample(c(46,58), Nrep*Npoint, replace = TRUE),
        sample(c(38,56), Nrep*Npoint, replace = TRUE), sample(c(-2,22), Nrep*Npoint, replace = TRUE), 
        sample(c(38,60), Nrep*Npoint, replace = TRUE), sample(c(46,62), Nrep*Npoint, replace = TRUE), 
        sample(c(26,44), Nrep*Npoint, replace = TRUE), sample(c(42,58), Nrep*Npoint, replace = TRUE), 
        sample(c(46,58), Nrep*Npoint, replace = TRUE), sample(c(38,56), Nrep*Npoint, replace = TRUE))

subj_t <- rep(c("s01", "s02"), each=Npoint*Ncond*Nrep);
cond_t <- rep(c("Quiet","1","1.41","2","2.82","4","TEN"), each=Nrep*Npoint, times=Nsubj);
rep_t  <- rep(c("a","b","c"), each=Npoint, times=Ncond*Nsubj); 

RAC_QST_a <- data.frame(data=data_a, subj=factor(subj_t), cond=factor(cond_t), rep=factor(rep_t))

library(ggplot2); library(forcats);

ggplot(RAC_QST_a, aes(x=fct_inorder(cond), y=data, group=interaction(subj,rep), color=subj, shape=rep, na.rm=TRUE)) + 
theme_bw() +  
stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "point", size = 2.5) +
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, geom = "errorbar",  size = .25, linetype = "solid") +
stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "line", size = .25, linetype = "dashed")  + 
stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", aes(group = cond), geom = "point", size = 3, shape=1, colour="black") + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(10,20,30,40,50,60), label = c(10,20,30,40,50,60)) + 
labs(title = "behavioural RAC", x = "Notch Central Freq [KHz]", y = "Threshold [dB SPL]")
```

I have this image, please see here: [http://imgur.com/LU8QJgm](https://imgur.com/LU8QJgm)
[image: pic 1]

Ideally I would like to get: 
[image: pic 2]

so, please how can I add also the black line between the circle and add the entry on the legged?

I wasn't able to adapt this answer [Add an entry to the legend for a manually added line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914151/how-to-add-an-entry-to-the-legend-for-a-manually-added-line) on my case …

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, thank to JoFrhwld's answer ([ggplot2: line connecting the means of grouped data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621963/ggplot2-line-connecting-the-means-of-grouped-data))

simply:

```
stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", aes(group = 1), linetype = "average"), 
           geom = "line", size = 1, shape=1, colour="black") +
scale_linetype_manual("", values = 3) +  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 1))) +
```